# What package has the statistical mean function in Python

Tags: mean

What package has the "statistical mean" function in Python.
I import scipy and numpy but get an error ***"mean" does not exist in scipy ***

Answer (score 1):

Both `scipy` and `numpy` have mean functions. Assuming you have both `numpy` and `scipy` properly installed on your machine and `Python` environment, it can be called like so:

```
import numpy
import scipy

items = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

numpy_answer = numpy.mean( items )
scipy_answer = scipy.mean( items )

print( numpy_answer )
print( scipy_answer )
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, but this is what I get, >>> Traceback (most recent call last):    >>>File"<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  >>>AttributorError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'mean' >>>